# AWS CloudFront - bypass cache depending on the presence of a certain header or cookie?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I wonder if it is possible to bypass the cache and hit the origin when a certain header or cookie exists in the requests? If yes, could you tell me the direction how to implement it, please?

Comment: Would adding the specific header or cookie to the cache key suffice? Or are you saying you don't want cache at all if they are present?

Comment: "you don't want cache at all if they are present?" - Yes @jellycsc  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to use [lambda edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html). Add a lambda function on viewer request to check for the specific header or cookie, and then add a `Cache-Control: no-store`.